# Link list is throwing exception and not printing first node

Tags: c++, pointers

link list is throwing exception
read access violation
this->cur was nullptr

```
int  y = 0;
cur = start;

do
{
    y++;
    cout << "**********************" << endl;
    cout << "  Node:" << y << endl;
    cout << "  Name:" << cur->name << endl;
    cout << "  Roll:" << cur->roll << endl;
    cout << "   Number:" << cur->number << endl;
    cout << "***********************" << endl;
    cur = cur->node;
} while (cur->node != NULL);//nullptr error
```

Comment: What is cur? Welcome to stack overflow, please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do a null check before using `cur->` to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

I guess your algorithm is wrong:

```
int  y = 0;
cur = start;

do
{
    ....
    cur = cur->node;   // at the end of the list cur->node is NULL
} while (cur->node != NULL);  // and here you dereference the null pointer
```

you probably want this:

```
...
cur = start;

do
{
    ....
    cur = cur->node;
} while (cur != NULL)
```

or maybe even this:

```
...
cur = start;

while (cur != NULL)
{
    ....
    cur = cur->node;
}
```

Comment: I think option 2 is better because it considers the scenario of empty linked list.